# How to detect current element using jQuery within nested ASP.NET listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, jquery-selectors

I have a nested listview containing multiple rows that each contain a ddl and a textbox, E.G.:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList id="myDDL" runat="server" CssClass="aDDL"
                onfocus="javaScript:$(function() { 
                $(<selector>).siblings.RemoveClass('wrappedElement');
                $(<selector>).addClass('wrappedElement');
             })" /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox id="myTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="aTextBox"
                onfocus="javaScript:$(function() { 
                $(<selector>).siblings.RemoveClass('wrappedElement');
                $(<selector>).addClass('wrappedElement');
             })" /></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

What I want to do is wrap the element that was clicked on. What is happening is that I am wrapping all "aDDL" or "aTextBox" elements. I need to find the ***selector*** for the element that was just focused on.

I tried [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959288/find-with-jquery-the-correct-listview-clientid-where-there-are-more-than-one-lis), but "this" or $(this) winds up pointing to the entire document.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just minor comment: you don't need to use the `javascript:` prefix on event handlers. It is only necessary when using javascript in the `href` of the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of items:

You don't need to prefix your code with `javascript:` which is only needed for link element that instead invoke a function on the `href` attribute `<a href="javascript:...">`. (Likely better in that case to bind to the `click` event.)

You also don't need to wrap your inline function with the jQuery object. Instead of coding: `onfocus="javaScript:$(function() { })"`, try `onfocus="function()"`.

Lastly, you can pass the `event` object as part of your handler call to gain access to the selector. Not sure it can be in-lined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function select(e) {
            var selector = e.target; // "select#options"
            var $selector = $(e.target) // jQuery object wrapping <select>
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="options" onfocus="select(event)">
        <option value="1">Dog</option>
        <option value="2">Cat</option>
        <option value="3">Horse</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Andy nailed it. The key is to use the event object because it always has an unambiguous event.target.id value.

Comment: Bob, found this and it could affect your use. target is no available in IE which uses srcElement instead. Use this to find your target: `var target = event.target || event.srcElement;`
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5301667/64262

Answer (score 0):

I would try defining your javascript in one place, outside of the template.  Something like this (from memory):

```
$(".aDDL").focus(function() {
     $(".wrappedElement").RemoveClass('wrappedElement');
     $(this).addClass('wrappedElement');
 });

// etc.
```

In my experience it works better to assign functions from outside the elements via selectors than to set them up as part of the HTML tag.

Comment: $(this) selects the whole window, not the current element

Comment: Out of curiosity:  do you still have the $(this) problem if you attach the handler to the elements via jQuery, as Sen Jacob and I suggested?  I'm wondering if the way you attached the function is causing $(this) to have a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

```
$(function() { 
    $(".aDDL,.aTextBox").focus(function() {
        $(".aDDL,.aTextBox").RemoveClass('wrappedElement');
        $(this).addClass('wrappedElement');
    });
});
```

And use this as your item template

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList id="myDDL" runat="server" CssClass="aDDL" /></td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox id="myTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="aTextBox" /></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

If you still want to do it inline, try like the following.

```
onfocus="$(function() { 
            var $this = $(document.activeElement);
            $this.siblings.RemoveClass('wrappedElement');
            $this.addClass('wrappedElement');
         })"
```

Comment: $(this) selects the whole window, not the current element. That's the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: $(this) is referring to which selector element you are using to fire the event. In your case, you are adding/removing the class in document.ready function itself, that is the reason your $(this) is referring to the current document.

Comment: I've edited my answer above. Please check whether it helps you out.